# Collapsing Toolbar Not working below Android 5.0

Tags: android, xml, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have problem with collapsing toolbar.

this code work on android 5+ but not work on android 4.1.2. I'm not much familiar with Collapsing Toolbar, I think I miss some thing.
On Android 4.1.2 when this activity starts just a black screen appears on my device nothing else, no error in Android Monitor.

Any suggestions?

Your help will be appreciated.
Thanks

**Profile.java**

```
public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if(getSupportActionBar() != null)
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

**activity_profile.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="10dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="20dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/b1"
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#456789">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="#333"
                android:textColor="#F0F0F0"
                android:text="A Demo Text View"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**style.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<activity
    android:name=".Profile"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why but below Android 5.0

Collapsing Toolbar does not work When assign `android:src=@drawable/b1` to
Image View in Collapsing toolbar.
After removing `android:src` it will work.
Just load image to ImageView in `onCreate` of activity.
Every things good now.

This worked for me